# Ember: Dynamically render a template

Tags: templates, ember.js, components

I have a component. Template of this component is "html data".
Those html data are composed by users and stored in database. They are loaded with ajax.

Normally, we just bind the component with html data. However, my "html data" also contains embedded ember component.
Ex:

```
<html> do something {{button action="abc"}} </html>.
```

So, what I have to do is to change dynamically the template of the component.
I tried by updating the template.

```
this.template = Ember.Handlebars.compile(html);
this.rerender();
```

However, the component does not  rerender with new template !!

Do you have an idea how to do this?

Thank you in advance

Green

Comment: Try assigning your compiled template to the list of themplates, like: `Ember.TEMPLATES['some-name'] = Em.Handlebars.compile('html here');`, then in your view, set it to be `templateName = 'some-name'`, the same as you created.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to call Ember.set method while setting values for Ember's objects. Use `this.set('template', template)` instead of `this.template = template`.

Demo (type new template into input and click on button): http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cuqofatisavu/1/edit?js,output

**Update (thx melc for [commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182315/ember-dynamically-render-a-template/26187476#comment41062439_26187476)):**
Set `layout` property instead of `template` if you need to change Ember.Component template.

Comment: I think for components `layout` needs to be set, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jareci/1/edit